# Get relationship of a queried relationship in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the clan members of the primary tournament, with only a season instance.

I fetch the primary tournament using a query on the `tournaments` relationship, I then call the `clans` relationship on the tournament model I just fetched.

Except.. it isn't a model anymore, I'm pretty sure its a query? Or a collection, sorry for my lack of understanding but in a simple explanation, I can no longer access relationships?

I need help in how I can do this with still being able to call `clans` after querying the tournament.

Here are my models.

```
class Season extends Model
{
    public function clans() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Clan::class);
    }

    public function tournaments() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tournament', 'season_id');
    }

    public function primaryTournament() {
        return $this->tournaments->where('is_primary', '1');
    }
}

class Tournament extends Model
{
    public function clans() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Clan::class);
    }

    public function season() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Season', 'season_id');
    }
}
```

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
$season = Season::all()->last();
$tournament = $season->primaryTournament();
$teams = $tournament->clans; // this is what erorrs
```

What's stopping me?

```
Property [clans] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$teams = $tournament->clans(); // with parenthesis
```

The problem is apparently in $tournament, which is a collection of Tournament class, and not an instance of a unique one (because it's obtained by ->where('is_primary', '1')), 
you can select the first instance by ->first() methode
or loop through $tournament values and access clan property.

Comment: This results in `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::clans does not exist.`.

Comment: return $tournament value to see if it's not empty

Comment: I don't think `$tournament` is empty as its saying its a class, a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`. But I went ahead and tested it anyway and it is a collection.

Comment: the problem can be in : primaryTournament() which return a collection, not a unique model value, to access clan value, try use a for loop with $tournament

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$teams = $tournament->clans();`
Clans is relation function on your model, you need to put parentheses. This should return a collection of the Clan class.